# Is windows app certification kit process necessary?

Tags: uwp

Is the Windows app certification kit's certification necessary, after creating App Packages to upload to store? Why I am asking this is, when I upload to store, it too takes some time to do some verification/validation after the app packages are uploaded, is that the same or part of the process done here in WACK? If both are same processes, I can skip this WACK process here, since it takes more time to complete. Any detailed info will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can submit your package without running the certification tests locally, but it's recommended to run them so you can fix any errors ahead of time. If you wait for the Store submission to complete, then your turnaround time for your release will be slower if you have any errors.